# Is it possible to downgrade ppa for a few days?

Tags: drivers, apt, ppa

I use [oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) ppa which updates every day. The last 3 days I see graphical glitches in games. Is there any way to downgrade ppa for a specific time (lets say -3 days) or to purge and install ppa again, but instead of installig the latest version, specify somehow -3 days, in order to install "old" files?

P.S. I need oibaf because I use Gallium Nine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I is not possible. Old packages are removed when new are uploaded. This is how Launchpad works.